# unexpected result concatenating simple strings in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, string, concatenation, sybase, variable-assignment

I'm getting unexpected results with a very simple bit of SQL, on Sybase.

```
declare @mystring char(30)

select @mystring = 'abc'

select 'mystring = ' + @mystring

select @mystring = @mystring + 'xyz'

select 'mystring = ' + @mystring
```

This returns:

```
mystring = abc                           
mystring = abc
```

Why doesn't the last select return 'abcxyz' ?

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this is because you have declared  `@mystring` as `char(30)` and  [All CHAR values are blank padded up to max-length](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/X315931.htm)

Declaring it as `varchar(30)` will do the trick :

```
declare @mystring varchar(30)

select @mystring = 'abc' 

select 'mystring = ' + @mystring

SELECT @mystring = @mystring + 'xyz'

select 'mystring = ' + @mystring
```

Comment: I don't know Sybase, but from what you say, using TRIM() at the right place would be another approach. Some SQL dialects also have a special concatenation operator that "squishes" strings together